# Only allow letters/numbers/underscore for HTML5 input with custom error message

Tags: javascript, html

I have been wrestling with this but can't figure it out.

I'd like to have an input for a form where a user is choosing their 'url' within the site

I'd like it to be only alphanumeric with underscores permitted, on failure to complete the pattern I'd like the error message: 'Please only use letters, numbers and underscores' to be shown.

I can't get the pattern to work while having the error message being shown, either the pattern doesn't accept something which is valid or it does accept something which isn't valid.

```
    input.form-control(type='text', pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$/, oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please only use letters, numbers and underscores')")
```

I'm using Jade, what am I doing wrong here? (Above example accepts invalid characters such as '$')

Comment: If I'm not mistaken setCustomValidity only works in input fields located in *<form>* tags. I highly suggest just creating your own pop up dialog box modal to show your message.

Or put it in a form

Comment: It seems to have been working, I just couldn't get the regexp working as far as I can tell

Comment: Strange! I've tested it and it works exactly as expected

Comment: @user10089632 I think there's a bug or something in the browsers, I ended up just coding something different & not relying on it